# Make Billing Emails in User Meta Lowercase Using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to mass update my database for the Wordpress User Meta table to make all billing emails lowercase.

The table `user_meta` has a `meta_key` column that with rows filled `billing_email`.

Then, the corresponding column `meta_value` has the email stored there.

I need to update the `meta_value` column for every entry where `meta_key = billing_email`.

I've tried the following SQL query, but it returns 0 rows when I simulate it, though I have 5600 rows when I search

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_usermeta
 WHERE meta_key LIKE 'billing_email'
```

Any tips would be appreciated. I have spent some time trying to better understand updating SQL but haven't found a precise answer to get the result I need.

**SQL Query to Make Billing Email Meta Value Lowercase**

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value` = LOWER(`meta_value`) WHERE `meta_key` = 'billing_email';
```

Comment: this doesn't work in mysql, or you must write a function that goes through every letter, The easiest way is ti use the poho function for that

Comment: Your query is correct and should indeed update all the entries with billing_email, and should always say `5600 rows affected`. You do commit? Do the update in the correct database? Howl to the moon?

Comment: @geertjanvdk howling at the moon actually did the trick. I think I just learned here that there's a difference in the results of simulating a query and actually running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs to do this in the future, the query I posted above works as expected.

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value` = LOWER(`meta_value`) WHERE `meta_key` = 'billing_email';
```